# PHP Page is Attempting to Download Instead of Display Content

Tags: php, web, file-association

**Problem**: I'm creating a website right now, it's my first time dealing with PHP after learning the basics. My index.php file, when viewed on my localhost, is attempting to download the file and bring up the file explorer prompt. Does this on both Chrome and Edge.

**Troubleshooting**:

1. I removed the file association.
2. Tried on Edge browser.
3. Looked online for answers. All other YouTube videos & forums I found including StackOverflow had previous questions about this but the answers were either outdated by like 10+ years or just didn't for me.

What do I do? Any help is appreciated, and reminder I'm new to PHP so please no super veteran-sized solutions, thanks.

Edit 01: I was told to share my URL so here it is:http://127.0.0.1:5500/index.php

Edit 02 (Solution): I didn't realize that the Live Server plugin for VSC was only for static HTML pages and not PHP pages. WebPajooh helped me with setup how to achieve a similar result using XAMPP.

Comment: What type of web server are you using to serve the file?

Comment: @NigelRen - I'm using Apache. Started using it via XAMPP yesterday.

Comment: Can you give an example of the url you are using in the browser to access your `index.php` file?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius - Sorry. Here's the URL: http://127.0.0.1:5500/index.php

Comment: It looks like the PHP handler is not configured.

Comment: port 5500 is an unusual port to be assigned to web traffic - did you select that number during setup? Have you located the `http.conf` file ( Apache config ) - details of the hostname, port and enabled extensions should be identifiable within it

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius - I have a plugin for Visual Studio Code called Live Server. Allows for live changes for designing and testing, etc. That's where the URL came from. As for the Apache config, I have no config of that name. I have 5 config files shown, but the closest thing to what you said is the httpd.conf. I went inside that file and control+F to search for 'host' and 'port' and didn't find any helpful info.

Comment: I've never used Visual Studio for PHP dev and have never seen `Live Server` but have you done the necessary setup as [indicated here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y4qqQeUDCBQ)?

Answer (score 1):

It was better to share your URL. I guess you are trying to access the PHP files by entering the file path, not the URL.

```
https://localhost/some_directory/some_file.php
```

If you are doing this, not entering the file path directly, check your web server configurations.

Comment: Yeah my fault, here's my URL: http://127.0.0.1:5500/index.php
As for your assumptions, I'm using Visual Studio Code for my coding, and I have this plugin called Live Server. That's how I'm getting to my local host. I'm not typing it in myself. I wasn't going to my file path and double clicking the file or anything if that's what you were assuming.

Comment: As I know, Xampp doesn't provide such addresses. Why don't you simply enter `localhost/file.php`? It uses port 80, leaving VSCode.

Comment: It takes me to the Xampp dashboard rather than the Index/Home page of my site.

Comment: Put your files in the `htdocs` or `www` folder. For example create `file.php` and enter `localhost/file.php`.

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question where would the htdocs or www folders be? In my website's file structure it's just 3 folders so far; css, fonts, & media then the individual files themselves. I haven't created any other folders yet.

Comment: Where have you installed XAMPP? Find it there.

Comment: Ok thanks Web. It worked, so just to clarify from now on when I want to test my pages when designing them, I would need to have the file placed in the htdocs folder? Or was this only because it was the index page?

Comment: You're welcome. You can create a directory for your project there, and put your files in your directory: `/htdocs/my-blog/some-file.php`.